# Change image to video

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe, responsive

I have a picture gallery where you can change the displayed image by "mouse entering" thumbnails shown on the same page.
Now I want to add a video to the gallery and it doesn't work with the code I provided for the images.
The problem is that I want the pictures and the video to stay a certain size. Since I want to add a video the img tag won't show the video as a source and when I change the img to iframe the video works just fine but the pictures aren't responsive anymore. Here's my code:

HTML

```
<div class="slide_work">
 <img src="images/Illustration/puzzled.png">
</div>

<div class="slide_thumbs">
 <div id ="thumbs_active" class="puzzled_img" style="background-image:url(images/Illustration/puzzled_img.png);"></div>
 <div class="puzzled_vid" style="background-image:url(images/Illustration/puzzled_vid.png);"></div>
```

CSS

```
.slide_work > img {
 float:right;
 height:auto;
 width:auto;
 max-height:70vh;
 max-width:100%;

 -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
 -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
 -o-transition: all 0.5s;
 transition: all 0.5s;
}
```

(I tried adding another block to the CSS where I change the "img" to "iframe" but it doesn't do anything in terms of the responsiveness of the images.)

JavaScript

```
$( ".puzzled_img" )
 .mouseenter(function() {
  $(".puzzled").attr('src', 'images/Illustration/puzzled.png');
  $(this).attr('id', 'thumbs_active');
  $(".puzzled_vid").removeAttr('id', 'thumbs_active');
})

$( ".puzzled_vid" )
 .mouseenter(function() {
  $(".puzzled").attr('src', 'https://player.vimeo.com/video/12345678');
  $(this).attr('id', 'thumbs_active');
  $(".puzzled_img").removeAttr('id', 'thumbs_active');
})
```

Comment: It would be great if you provide [minimum reproducible code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to see the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of replacing the `<img>` tag's `src` attribute or replace the element, just add more slides and show / hide the ones that are currently being hovered based on an index value.

The example below has two slides, where one has the class `hidden`. You can hide this element with CSS. The thumbnails have a `data-attribute` with an index value, telling you which element in the slides list they control. Whenever you hover a thumbnail it will look for the slide with right index and shows that one while hiding every other slide.

```html
<div class="slide_work">
  <div class="slide_item">
    <img src="images/Illustration/puzzled.png">
  </div>
  <div class="slide_item hidden">
    <iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/12345678"></iframe>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="slide_thumbs">
  <div data-index="0" id="thumbs_active" class="puzzled_img" style="background-image:url(images/Illustration/puzzled_img.png);"></div>
  <div data-index="1" class="puzzled_vid" style="background-image:url(images/Illustration/puzzled_vid.png);"></div>
</div>
```

```js
var $slides = $('.slide_item');

$('.slide_thumbs > div').on('mouseenter', function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  var index = $this.data('index');
  var $target = $slides.eq(index);
  $slides.addClass('hidden');
  $target.removeClass('hidden');
});
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer!
I have to admit that I am not very good at coding and since I didn't code for about 3 1/2 years I had some problems understanding why you chose this solution. That's why I decided not to do it this way. But I'd like to thank you that you got me out of my "I have to you use the same tag for the image and the video"-bubble so I could find my own solution. But thank you for providing this solution for people who do understand your code!

Answer (score 0):

That's the way I decided to do it in the end:

HTML

```
<div class="slide_work">
    <div class="slide_item_img">
        <img class="slide_item_img" src="images/Illustration/puzzled.png"></div>
    <div class="slide_item_vid" style="display:none; float:right">
        <iframe class="slide_item_vid" style="display:none; float:right" src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/12345678" width="640" height="747" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; fullscreen" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
$( ".puzzled_img" )
  .mouseenter(function(){
    $(".slide_item_vid").css("display", "none");
    $(".slide_item_img").css("display", "inherit");
    $(this).attr('id', 'thumbs_active');
    $(".puzzled_vid").removeAttr('id', 'thumbs_active');
  })

$( ".puzzled_vid" )
  .mouseenter(function(){
    $(".slide_item_img").css("display", "none");
    $(".slide_item_vid").css("display", "inherit");
    $(this).attr('id', 'thumbs_active');
    $(".puzzled_img").removeAttr('id', 'thumbs_active');
  })
```